# Issue using geocoding to return array of land-based coordinates

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a piece of functionality to effectively return an array of land-based coordinates. I have used Google's geocoder to effectively create one-off land-based coordinates however I want to integrate it into a system whereby an array of land-based coordinates is eventually created, by using a while block, so the function is called until the requisite number of land-based coordinates are determined. I consider that the below should work however, when the function is called, the page (using JSFiddle) crashes.

I am at a loss as to why this is the case as I believe that the number should be reduced each time a location-based coordinate is found and if one isn't found the function would be called until one is found (which should be at some point in the future).

Any guidance would be appreciated. The public fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/grabbeh/sajfb/

```
 var map;
 var coords = [];
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

window.onload = function () {
   center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.717, -74.006);

    var options = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
  //randomLandBasedCoords(2, function(coords){
  // addMarkersToMap(coords);
  //});
  };

function addMarkersToMap(places) {
  for (var i = 0, j = places.length; i < j; i++) {
     placeMarker(places[i]);
     };
};

function placeMarker(location) {
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    flat: true,
   });
};

function randomLandBasedCoords(number, fn) {
  if (number > 0) {
    while (number > 0) {
        // create random coordinate
        var lng = (Math.random() * 360 - 180);
        var lat = (Math.random() * 180 - 90);
        var randomCoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        // call geocoder function to check if coordinate is land-based with a timeout    to control flow (maybe)
        setTimeout(geocoder.geocode({
            location: randomCoordinate
            }, function (results, status) {
               if (status == "OK" && results) {
                  var landCoordinate = randomCoordinate;
                  coords.push(landCoordinate);
                  number--;
               }
           }), 250);
       }
   }
   return fn(coords);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function randomLandBasedCoords(number,fn) {
    // create random coordinate
    var lng = (Math.random() * 360 - 180);
    var lat = (Math.random() * 180 - 90);
    var randomCoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    // call geocoder function to check if coordinate is land-based
    geocoder.geocode({
        location: randomCoordinate
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            randomLandBasedCoords(number,fn);
        } else if (status == "OK" && results) {
            var landCoordinate = randomCoordinate;
            coords.push(landCoordinate);
            if (coords.length < number) {
                randomLandBasedCoords(number,fn);
            } else {
                return fn(coords);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for this. It's definitely an improvement, but still in a position where non-land-based coordinates appear on the map. This is the case even where 'number' is 1. All in all rather puzzling to me. http://jsfiddle.net/grabbeh/jsLZS/ is the fiddle.

Comment: Actually, looks like it's something which I can fine-tune depending on geocoder results presumably so I'll accept this as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code is falling over when you do your '// call geocoder function to check if coordinate is land-based' function.

Error:

```
Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
}), 250);
```

Haven't got the time to debug that now but here's a sample I've successfully used in the past which looks more simple:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { // -- Has a result been returned ?
    DO process stuff
}else{ // -- Location not returned - must be in the sea !
    DO in the sea stuff
}
```

*Might be of some help ?*

Comment: Little extra from the same site, I'm using this code - "if( results[0].formatted_address.indexOf('UK') == -1){ // -- Check if chosen location is in the UK" to check if the location chosen is in the UK. - Might be of some use...

Comment: Thanks Pat - I think I'm left in a similar position as with the existing code. Removing the setTimeout doesn't lead to any improvement. Will continue tinkering...